# Google Fonts, SSL, Mixed Content Issues

Tags: html, css, ssl, fonts, mixed-content

I'm having an issue with Google Web Fonts and SSL. Basically my html code was calling for the google web font's css file using "http", like so,

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Because of this, my site is showing "mixed content warnings" and a "shield" in the Google Chrome URL bar, and just as well shows an exclamation point by the lock in the Firefox URL bar.

So basically I changed the "http" in the referenced url to "https" like so:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and the warnings disappear...BUT...now the google font does not display correctly. And I do not know why.

My website is here:

https://www.cleaningleader.com

Tried loading fonts locally, didn't seem to work. Also tried using schema agnostic URL = "//....", and that does not work either.

I do not know why the two solutions above do not work when I thought they should. Any ideas? Please feel free to elaborate on the issue and any topics I've touched upon. Thanks.

Comment: In your page font is called inside `<body>` tag. Do it inside `<head>`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Still fails under same conditions, and locally and via a schema agnostic URL.

Comment: I didn't say it will solve your problem, you just can't put `<link>` tags inside `<body>`. It must go in `<head>`. Although when I test it on your website with font link inside head it works fine. So you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Yes I must be doing something wrong if you noticed it was working fine with font link inside head. Can you tell me exactly where you pasted in the header and what exactly you pasted in the head tags?

Comment: I just put https link to google font inside `<head>`. Nothing more.